# Custom Paging in DataPager control

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datapager, raddatapager

can any one have idea how to implement custom paging in silverlight / telerik DataPager like asp.net pager control

Suppose i have a count of records in table suppose 100000 My page size is 1000 so

at first point (page load) get only first 1000 records and  after when move ahead (click on another page ) on page index 2 so again go on service and fetch 1001 to 2000 records from server and bind to grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for telerik 
use datapager as unbound mode

```
this.data = Enumerable.Range( 0, 100 ).ToList();
    this.radDataPager.ItemCount = data.Count;
```

and implement pager index changed

ref http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddatapager-features-unbound-mode.html